# CLOB Update Failing On Content Below Character Limit

Tags: oracle, coldfusion, clob

I am trying to update a CLOB field using form input in ColdFusion 8. The data being submitted is no more than 10KB in size, yet I get the `ORA-01704: string literal too long` error.

```
<cfquery name="updatePubs" datasource="#authConfig.getConfigSetting('datasource')#">
  UPDATE members
  SET publication = '#publications#'
  WHERE campus_key = #id#
</cfquery>
```

Is there an alternate way to do this? It updates fine for data just below 4KB, but above that it throws the error.

Comment: Are you sure that the datasource returned by `#authConfig.getConfigSetting('datasource')#` has CLOB enabled in the ColdFusion administrator?

Comment: Yes, it is enabled for this datasource.

Comment: Have you tried using `<cfqueryparam>` tags?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try wrapping the variables within your query with `<cfqueryparam>` tags.  Like this:

```
<cfquery name="updatePubs" datasource="#authConfig.getConfigSetting('datasource')#">
  UPDATE members
  SET publication = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="CF_SQL_CLOB" value="#publications#">
  WHERE campus_key = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="CF_SQL_INTEGER" value="#id#">
</cfquery>
```

*Note that I am assuming your `id` is of type integer in my example.*

The `<cfqueryparam>` tag does the following:

- Allows the use of SQL bind parameters, which improves performance.
- Ensures that variable data matches the specified SQL type.
- Allows long text fields to be updated from a SQL statement.
- Escapes single-quotation marks in string variables.

To benefit from the enhanced performance of bind variables, use cfqueryparam for all ColdFusion variables, and your DBMS must support bind variables. If a DBMS does not support bind parameters, ColdFusion validates and substitutes the validated parameter value back into the string. If validation fails, it returns an error message.

Here is a link to the [documentation for cfqueryparam](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7f6f.html)

Comment: Brilliant! I assume by this update it treats a non-queryparam variable closer to a varchar2 in terms of size limit?

Comment: I assume it is something like that. By using `<cfqueryparam>` ColdFusion will verify the data type and for DBMS that support binding variables it can do that when it prepares the SQL statement. And double-bonus using the tag also helps protect you from some SQL injection attacks. I will add a bit more to my answer from the documentation. Of special note to your issue is the third bullet.